# Recursive PHP function gets only first values

Tags: php, recursion, nested, iteration

I'm having an issue with below code. I'm trying for some time now, and I believe I must be blind and I do not see something obvious. Can you point at this obvious thing?

Function ought to get all categories and it's names. Takes IDs correctly, but names only for first category and first subcategory.

```
function collect($id, $current = null) {
    global $db_1;

    $s = "SELECT category.id as id, category_i18n.name as name from category,category_i18n WHERE category.parent_id= '$id' AND category.visible = '1' AND category_i18n.culture='en' AND category.id = category_i18n.id ORDER BY category.order_asc ASC";
    $r = mysql_query($s, $db_1);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $children = array();
    if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
        while ($row) {
            $children['name'] = $row['name'];
            $children[$row['id']] = collect($row['id']);
        }
    }
else
    {
            $children['name'] = $row['name'];
    }

    return $children;
}
```

EDIT:

EDIT2:

After changes I'm getting array like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Cat"
  ["id"]=>
  string(5) "10404"
  ["children"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Subcat"
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "10410"
    ["children"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

I think it is not problem with mysql query, as in phpmyadmin it works and shows all data properly...

Comment: Your `while ($row)` loop should loop forever, since it never fetches a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED :

It seems that you have only 1 level of subdirectory. Your function does this :

1) First it fetches the name and id of the given category.
2) It uses the obtained id to fetch the name of the subcategory which has parent_id = the previously fetched id.
3) Here comes the problem. Due to recursion it again calls `collect()` with the id of this subcategory. But there is no subcategory for this, so it returns null.

That is,

1st Parent (id1) -> Subcategory(id2) -> Subcategory(id2) and so on.

You can use this to get as many levels of categories as you want :

```
function collect($id, $current = null) {
    global $db_1;

    $s = "SELECT category.id as id, category_i18n.name as name from category,category_i18n WHERE category.parent_id= '$id' AND category.visible = '1' AND category_i18n.culture='en' AND category.id = category_i18n.id ORDER BY category.order_asc ASC";
    $r = mysql_query($s, $db_1);
    $temp = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
        { 
            $temp[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $temp[$row['id']]['children'] = collect($row['id']); //Get further children (Recursive)
            if(!$temp[$row['id']]['children']) {continue;} // If FALSE is returned, means that this category has no sub categories. Move onto next one.
        }
    }
    else {return FALSE;} //No rows present, return FALSE

    return $temp;
}
```

This code is not tested. You will get an array in the following format

```
$parent[parent_id] -> [name]

                   -> [children] -> FALSE (if subdirectories are not present)

                                 -> [children_id] #1 -> [name]

                                                     -> [children]

                                 -> [children_id] #2 and so on.
```

UPDATE : you were getting only the last result, because I forgot one thing. The `$temp[]` array was getting overwritten every time in the loop.

Comment: I changed this, and the result is the same. I will post array which I get in my question.

Comment: @codelame if you can update your answer with the logic behind your recursive function, then I can help you quicker. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get category tree ids and names. Function gets ids, but only first names, as you can see on array updated in my question. Sorry - I thought it's obvious what I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: thank you very much for your time :) I can't test it right now, but I hope it will work. About levels - I try to write function which will not need to know how deep it should go. Should work for 1 category and subcategories only, and should work for 10 levels :) This is my idea :) Should go as deep as it can.

Comment: @codelame I see. Then I will update the answer according to your needs.

Comment: I checked and it still fails. Funny thing is that mysql result has 10 categories. Some of them have children, and/or grandchildren. Function you prepared gets ONLY category no. 10 and one (first) of it's children. So gets only last category, and first child. (I've checked that with changing ORDER BY from ASC do DESC) Strange :)

Comment: @codelame it was a typo. The `$temp` array was getting overwritten every time in the loop. check now..

Comment: There is still error, but typo again I think ;) you need to remove second call of mysql_fetch_array in loop. Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to remove the inner fetch. How foolish of me! :P